# When can one find a neighborhood for a point?

Tags: general-topology

When can one find a neighborhood for a point?

I figured out this confusion when considering the concept of *locally Euclidean*. $M$ is locally euclidean, if for every point of $M$ one can find a neighborhood, which is homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But when can one find such neighborhood? Or does the def. for *locally Euclidean* already presuppose that it exists (that is, it exists when one calls a set *locally Euclidean*, so the concept of *locally Euclidean* itself doesn't say about how/when to find such neighborhood).

$V$ is neighborhood of point $p$ if exists open ball with centre $p$ and radius $r$ s.t.

$$\{ x \in X : d(x,p) < r \}=B(p,r)$$

is contained in $V$.

Since I believe that one isn't constrained for e.g. $M= \emptyset$, then e.g. for this $M$ one cannot find a neighborhood?

Then what properties lead to such neighborhood existing? Connectivity etc.

Comment: So, if $M=\varnothing$, then of course it contains no neighborhoods. All this means is that $M$ is not locally Euclidean.  But your question is quite muddled.

You ask,
"But when can one find such neighborhood? Or does the def. for locally Euclidean already presuppose that it exists (that is, it exists by definition of locally Euclidean)."

How could the definition presuppose that such a neighborhood exists?  That sounds like your reasoning is circular here.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski If the definition of *locally Euclidean* is that such neighborhood exists. And that the definition does not consider, when one can find such neighborhood. Only that, *when one does find it*, then it's *called* locally Euclidean. Or what does *locally Euclidean* mean then?

Comment: *If* you can find such a neighbourhood for every point of $M$ then $M$ is locally Euclidean. *If* for some point of $M$ you can't, then it is not. -- Incidentally, $M=\emptyset$ is locally Euclidean because indeed for every point in $M$ you can fund such a neighbourhood, in the same way as every unicorn has blue eyes.

Comment: So it's not entirely clear what your question is? Are you looking for examples of spaces that are not locally Euclidean?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski More like, are there some general properties of sets that *lead to* such neighborhoods being definable? Connectivity etc.?

Comment: Well I'm not enough of an expert to answer such a broad question. But here's an example, let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2=y^2\}$.  This set is the union of the line $y=x$ and $y=-x$.  This set will be locally Euclidean at every point except $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no expectation of there being a recipe for finding such a locally Euclidean neighbourhood. Such a neighbourhood either exists for all points, or this is not the case. Mathematicians are mostly platonists. We can work with the assumption that such spaces exist and there are lots of motivating examples (like curves and surfaces) but for abstract spaces, if we call it locally Euclidean, then we just suppose we are given such neighbourhoods for each point, entirely in the abstract and then study the consequences that such a structure has on the properties of such a space etc.

If we want to apply such theory for concretely defined spaces we should indeed check that the definition holds for that space. This entails find neighbourhoods in the space and homeomorphisms from those neighbourhoods to Euclidean ones.